# Type of this Conic section

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, conic-sections, quadratics

I want to determine, to which type the following Conic sections belong to:
$$
\begin{align}
\textrm{(i)}&\quad-8x^2+12xy-6x+8y^2-18y+8=0\\
\textrm{(ii)}&\quad5x^2-8xy+2x+5y^2+2y+1=0
\end{align}
$$

To (i)

Matrix notation:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}x&y\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-8&6\\6&8\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}+2\begin{pmatrix}-3&-9\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}+8=0\\
$$
$A=\begin{pmatrix}-8&6\\6&8\end{pmatrix}$

Eigenvalues are $\lambda_1=10,\lambda_2=-10$

Eigenvectors: $v_{\lambda_1}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\3\end{pmatrix}, v_{\lambda_2}=\begin{pmatrix}-3\\1\end{pmatrix}$

diagonal matrix $D=\begin{pmatrix}10&0\\0&-10\end{pmatrix}$

rotation matrix $B=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}&\frac{-3}{\sqrt{10}}\\\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}\end{pmatrix}$

Let $x=Bx'$

$\Rightarrow x^TAx+u^Tx=x'^TB^TABx'+u^TBx'=x'^TDx'+u^TBx'$

Calculating $u'^T=u^TB$

$u'^T=2(\begin{pmatrix}-3&-9\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}&\frac{-3}{\sqrt{10}}\\\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{10})}\end{pmatrix}
)=\begin{pmatrix}-6\sqrt{10}&0\end{pmatrix}$

So the transformed quadric is:

$10x'^2-6\sqrt{10}x'-10y'^2+8=0$

I know, that the solution must be $10x^2-10y^2=1$, but completing the square didn't get  me there... Is my work so far correct? Where is my mistake? Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Well the second equation

$$ 5 x^2 - 8 x y + 5 y^2 + 2 x + 2 y + 1 = 0 $$

can be written as

$$
5 \Big( \big[ x - x_o \big] + x_o \Big)^2
- 8 \Big( \big[ x - x_o \big] + x_o \Big) \Big( \big[ y - y_o \big]
+ y_o \Big) + 5 \Big( \big[ y - y_o \big] + y_o \Big)^2\\
+ 2 \Big( \big[ x - x_o \big] + x_o \Big)
+ 2 \Big( \big[ y - y_o \big] + y_o \Big) + 1 = 0
$$

so

$$
5 \big[ x - x_o \big]^2
- 8 \big[ x - x_o \big] \big[ y - y_o \big]
+ 5 \big[ y - y_o \big]\\
+ \Big( 10 x_o - 8 y_o + 2 \Big) \big[ x - x_o \big]
+ \Big( 10 y_o - 8 x_o + 2 \Big) \big[ y - y_o \big]\\
+ 5 x_o^2 - 8 x_o y_o + 5 y_o^2 + 2 x_o + 2 y_o + 1 = 0
$$

So $x_o = -1$ and $y_o = -1$ gives

$$
5 \big[ x + 1 \big]^2
- 8 \big[ x + 1 \big] \big[ y + 1 \big]
+ 5 \big[ y + 1 \big]^2 = 1\\
$$

This can be written as

$$
9 \big[ x + 1 \big]^2
- 18 \big[ x + 1 \big] \big[ y + 1 \big]
+ 9 \big[ y + 1 \big]^2\\
+ \big[ x + 1 \big]^2
+ 2 \big[ x + 1 \big] \big[ y + 1 \big]
+ \big[ y + 1 \big]^2 = 2\\
$$

so

$$
9 \big( x - y \big)^2 + \big( x + y + 2 \big)^2 = 2
$$

which is an ellipse with the axis $x-y=0$ and $x+y+2=0$.

Comment: Why is $x_0 =-1$ and $y_0=-1$?

Comment: To remove the linear terms...